# sql group by with inner join

Tags: sql

I want to group by the outcome of this query as shown below.

```
select takes.namestudent, takes.pointscourse    
from takes    
inner join follows    
on follows.idstudent = takes.idstudent    
where follows.completedprogram = 'yes'
```

outcome:

```
'Dan Purple',4
'Dan Purple',2
'Dan Purple',3
'Dan Purple',2
'Dan Purple',2
'Bob White',2
'Bob White',4
'Bob White',3
'Bob White',3
'Bob White',2
```

But i want it like this:

```
'Dan Purple', 13
'Bob White', 14
```

I tried several group by or sum possibilities but I cannot get it right.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post your best try with `GROUP BY`. Then we could answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select takes.namestudent, sum(takes.pointscourse) as total
from takes 
inner join follows on follows.idstudent = takes.idstudent 
where follows.completedprogram = 'yes'
group by takes.namestudent
```